# Edit to restore the original intent of the author was rejected

Tags: discussion, edits

My edit was rejected by a vote of 2/3:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21622119

I tried to restore the original intent of the asker who was requesting information on how to append a line of text, somewhere in a text file. Their original post illustrated the *final output* like this:

> Final result:
>
> Some line of text *(existing)*
>
> Added line of text *(new)*

An editor changed this to:

> Final result:
>
> **Existing**:
>
> Some line of text
>
> **New**:
>
> Added line of text

My argument is that splitting up the "final result" between headings makes it read like the existing line is supposed to be replaced by the other line. It makes much more sense to have the "final result" show the *desired result*. To that end, I put the two lines together:

> Final result:
>
> ```
> Some line of text
> Added line of text
> ```

If you review the original post, you will see that this was the intent of the asker and how they actually tried to write it, originally. Almost nothing else was changed in my edit, except to remove bold around the "line to add" text. There was no point in making that into a heading. There are no other headings and it is only for one line.

I don't think that the evaluation of my edit was fair. In which case, the suggested course of action seems to be to post here. So, I hope that I can get some kind of second opinion and ideally, have the rejection changed to accepted.

Comment: I think you did all that is necessary- commented so OP can fix up the post... but they don’t seem to care that much as they did not show up after Dec 7 when they created the post. The question is likely duplicate so I would not worry too much about it (also you are likely right in your suggestion)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks. Yes, I noticed that the asker hadn't returned. We don't even know if they ever saw the answers :-/

Comment: That change seemed ok for, but I wonder about the dots inside the `<>`. Is that required in batch files or just something OP added to avoid that being interpreted as HTML tags due to bad formatting? If the latter, then that should be fixed as well.

Comment: @Tom Yes, the dots were also inconsistent. Only the OP knows.

Comment: It might have helped if your edit summary had included that the text you were changing was added by somebody else. (One of the reviewers rejecting it thought you were the one changing the author's intent.) In review, we only see the current version of the post and your changes. It isn't obvious what parts of the post aren't from the original author.

Comment: @BSMP Ah, that is a good point. Thanks for noticing that.